# C++ MFC - Application crashes upon attribute definition

Tags: c++, class, mfc, nested-class

I have a C++ class, ClassA. I want to, inside ClassA, define ClassB and then define an attribute of ClassA of type ClassB.

I have another class, ClassC which holds a pointer variable of the type ClassA. If I attempt to point this pointer to an instance of ClassA, the application crashes. However if I remove the attribute m_classB, everything works fine. So something about the instance of ClassC attempting to point to the ClassA instance that contains a ClassB is causing it to crash, but a ClassA that does NOT contain a ClassB is fine... if that makes sense.

My code is below:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) ClassA
{
public:
    class ClassB {
    public:
        int m_nID;
        CString m_string;

        ClassB() :
            m_nID(-1),
            m_string(_T(""))
        {

        }
    };

    ClassB m_classB; // If i comment this out, then the application loads no problem
};
```

What is quite strange is that if I replace `ClassB m_classB;` with `vector<ClassB> m_vclassB;`, it all works fine.

If I use `ClassB* m_classB` instead then the same crash occurs.

Cheers!

Comment: How you are using this class. CRT Settings are both equal for the projects?

Comment: My debugger isn't working right now

Comment: @xMRi Okay I was mistaken; after further debugging the application does not crash on instantiation of ClassA... I'm actually trying to assign an instance of the class created with dynamically allocated memory to a pointer attribute of another object. I have updated the question to solve this. And I'm sorry, I don't know what CRT Settings are; could you enlighten me?

Comment: The CRT settings are prject settings. They define how the CRT is used in your projects. Because I see __declspec Export I suppose that you have a DLL and a EXE. But you didn't wrote about that.